# How to pass `palletId` and `methodId` when constructing an Instruction::Transact call?

Tags: xcm

I want to construct a customized *call* in `Instruction::Transact`. But how can I pass parameters [`palletId`](https://github.com/VegeBun-csj/Proof-Chain/blob/main/pallets/xclient/src/lib.rs#L79) and [`methodId`](https://github.com/VegeBun-csj/Proof-Chain/blob/main/pallets/xclient/src/lib.rs#L80) to it?

I configure the `palletId` and `methodId` in my `Config`, which can be set in my [*Runtime*](https://github.com/VegeBun-csj/Proof-Chain/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L638). But how can I pass parameters to it?

---

Here's my pallet code:

1. This is my customize `call`

   ```
    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Default, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
    pub struct XregisterCall<AccountId> {
        // two call parameter: palletId and methodId
        call_index: [u8; 2],
        // method parameter: register_account and register_name
        account: AccountId,
        name: Vec<u8>,
    }
   ```
2. This is my `Config`

   ```
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;

        /// The XCM sender module.
        type XcmSender: SendXcm;

        /// Xregister Pallet ID in xregister server
        type XregisterPalletID: Get<u8>;

        /// Xregister Method ID in xregister server
        type XregisterMethodID: Get<u8>;

        /// Xregister maximum weight
        type XregisterWeightAtMost: Get<u64>;
    }
   ```
3. In my dispatchable `call`, the code is this:

   ```
    let call = XregisterCall::<T::AccountId>::new(
                T::XregisterPalletID::get(), // palletId
                T::XregisterMethodID::get(), // pallet中的mathod Id
                who.clone(),                 // accountId
                name.clone(),                // registered name
            );

            // build the xcm transact message
            let message = Xcm(vec![Instruction::Transact {
                origin_type: OriginKind::Native,
                require_weight_at_most: T::XregisterWeightAtMost::get(),
                call: call.encode().into(),
            }]);

            // send the message to xregister server chain
            match T::XcmSender::send_xcm(
                (1, Junction::Parachain(4000u32.into())),  // 4000 is the destination parachain Id.
                message,
            ) {
                // send_xcm结果是一个result
                Ok(()) => {
                    // emit the event if send successfully
                    Self::deposit_event(Event::Xregister(who, name));
                    Ok(().into())
                },
                Err(_) => Err(Error::<T>::XcmSendError.into()),
            }
   ```
4. My runtime config code is this:

   https://github.com/VegeBun-csj/Proof-Chain/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L635

In the above, I configure the `XregisterPalletID` and `XregisterMethodID`, so that I can pass the two parameters in runtime. Is this scheme OK? So the question is that I don't know how can I pass parameter in Runtime. If it's wrong, how can I correct it? Or are there any examples for me to take? I'm not familiar with xcm customize calls.

Comment: Please share the snippets of code here for people to review, so they don't have to parse your fill code. Great to reference it though in full, best by line numbers if possible as you have done

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your pallet's functionality is, but *any* configurable parameter for the pallet should appear as a parameter to the dispatch function, i.e. this here:

```
pub fn xregister(origin: OriginFor<T>, name: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo
```

needs to be changed to:

```
pub fn xregister(origin: OriginFor<T>, name: Vec<u8>, pallet_id: u8, method_id: u8) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo
```

... in order for the caller of `xregister` to be able to specify the `palletId` and the `methodId` in the call.

Comment: HI, is there any customize call in parachain XCM example? thanks! i want to learn it.
if i want to pass parameters in call, how to pass `palletId` and `methodId`

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you first need to modify the `xregister` dispatchable function on the pallet before you can use `Transact`. It is not possible to "customize" the call function while constructing the XCM `Transact` instruction.